# Suggestion to remove Special Character in a Oracle column

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to remove the special character which mentioned in below words.

```
Ex: NANDKISHOR SINGH��, NANDKI��SHOR SINGH, ��SHOR SINGHNANDKI
```

Kindly assist to me..

Comment: Why do you like to remove them rather than fixing the display issue?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually I need to use the trimed data to export it in EXCEL procedure. As i get ORA 4063 error i thought of fixing the special characters issue in the data.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
UPDATE table SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(ASCIISTR(column), '\\[[:xdigit:]]{4}', '')
```

`ASCIISTR` will convert special chars to `\dddd` and then `REGEXP_REPLACE` will replace all `\dddd` with `''`

Comment: thanks for the reply. The above one works if the special character is at the end. It removes all the character after the special character in a string. 

For Eg: 
        Original Value              -        Return Value
NANDKISHOR SINGH��    -   NANDKISHOR SINGH
NANDKI��SHOR SINGH    -   NANDKI
��SHOR SINGHNANDKI    -   

But i need as 
              Original Value        -     Return Value
NANDKISHOR SINGH��    -   NANDKISHOR SINGH
NANDKI��SHOR SINGH    -   NANDKISHOR SINGH
��SHOR SINGHNANDKI    -   SHOR SINGHNANDKI

Comment: @ChandruNatarajan Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Please edit your question and provide more examples and more detailous description

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issues which I had fixed by using this update query

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME = REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '[^0-9A-Za-z]', '') 
WHERE REQUIRED_CONDITION_IF_ANY ;
```